# Not getting proper error code

Tags: vbscript, plink

When i am running below code from vbscript always i am getting error status as 0 in a log file irrespective of error code but when i run the same code from command prompt i am getting error code 127. below is the vbscript code

```
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

str = "plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw gbG8qs4D /remote_linux_server/listoffiles.sh > C:\count_data_csv.txt"

error = "error %ErrorLevel%" >> C:\count_data_csv.txt"

objShell.run  "cmd /k " & str & "&" & error

Set objShell = Nothing
```

Please let me know why there is a difference in error code

But after running above vbscript command if i check error code in command prompt i am getting error code 127 which is correct but my vbscript doesn't able to redirect same error code in count_data_csv.txt :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. used reserved word `error` for a variable, replaced by `Xerror`
2. `cmd /V:ON ...` enables delayed expansion which is put to use by `!ErrorLevel!` instead of `%errorlevel%`
3. missing `echo`

---

```
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
str = "plink.exe -ssh user@host -pw gbG8qs4D /remote_linux_server/listoffiles.sh > C:\count_data_csv.txt"
Xerror = "echo error !ErrorLevel!>>C:\count_data_csv.txt"
objShell.run  "cmd /V:ON /k " & str & "&" & Xerror
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, Your code work like a charm. Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

`errorlevel` isn't set yet when you use it in a multiple command:

```
DOS C:\Documents and Settings\eh
echo %errorlevel%
0 <--- all is well

DOS C:\Documents and Settings\eh
dur *.* & echo %errorlevel%
'dur' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  <--- something fishy happenend
0 <--- errorlevel still looks good

DOS C:\Documents and Settings\eh
echo %errorlevel%
9009  <--- better late then never
```

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), .Run returns the exit code of the called program when invoked with the bWaitOnReturn/3rd parameter set to True:

> The following VBScript code does the same thing, except it specifies
>   the window type, waits for Notepad to be shut down by the user, and
>   saves the error code returned from Notepad when it is shut down.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return = WshShell.Run("notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName, 1, true)
```

So try if going by the book works for you and plink.

**P.S. To raise your hopes:**

```
>> Set oWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
>> iRet = oWS.Run("plink -ssh -pw Geheim1 eh@uw ""pipapo -l tmp.txt""", 0, True)
>> WScript.Echo iRet
>>
127
```